# filter() function failing in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, polyfills

I am making use of an IntersectionObserver polyfill from w3c. This particular [line](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/blob/master/polyfill/intersection-observer.js#L214) is breaking in Safari. Upon investigation I found out that, the below snippet does not work in Safari but does so in Chrome and Firefox. Is there an alternative to the issue? I am passing `0.3` to _initThresholds()

```
  IntersectionObserver.prototype._initThresholds = function(opt_threshold) {
  var threshold = opt_threshold || [0];
  if (!Array.isArray(threshold)) threshold = [threshold];

  return threshold.sort().filter(function(t, i, a) {
    console.log(t, i, a);
    if (typeof t != 'number' || isNaN(t) || t < 0 || t > 1) {
      throw new Error('threshold must be a number between 0 and 1 inclusively');
    }
    return t !== a[i - 1];
  });
};
```

If the above snippet is run on Safari it returns:

```
`0.3 – 0 – undefined` in Safari
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a[i - 1]')
```

On Chrome and Firefox it returns:

```
   0.3 0 Array [ 0.3 ]
   Array [ 0.3 ]
```

Comment: That code seems pointless anyway.

Comment: Which part of the code is pointless?

Comment: The function will always leave you with that same table `[0.3]`.  You can fix the code by changing the `return` to make sure `i` is greater than zero, which it will never be because you've got a 1-element array.

Comment: If its helpful, I ve updated the description with the log statements.

Comment: Right so `return i === 0 || t !== a[i - 1];` Without seeing more code it still looks useless.

Comment: I ve updated the snippet as is from the Polyfill.

Comment: I gave you the line to fix, but if you don't want to change it then log a bug against that project. *edit* wait, never mind; if you're getting `undefined` for the third parameter, then it's `.filter()` that's broken. What Safari version are you using?

Comment: What version of Safari? Works fine on 12.0.3

Comment: @Pointy I think you are missing the point of this method: it excludes duplicate values in the given input. `initThresholds([0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1])` => `[0.1, 0.2, 0.5]`. All values are sorted and dupes are removed, so it can be set as unique thresholds values. The code is fine.

Comment: Yes I see that; as originally posted it didn't make much sense.

Comment: I am using the 12.0.3

Comment: Then it's a no repro for me.

Comment: The website had overloaded the filter function and my code wasnt working for that reason. Thanks for the help.